# Servlet 2.5 on WAS 8

Tags: websphere-8

Is there any way to use servlet 2.5 specification on WAS 8.0, by default he try to use 3.0 but the portal which I'm using doesn't support new servlet specification and I've to run it on lower version.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only servlet container included in WebSphere Application Server 8.0 is the one that supports the Servlet 3.0 specification.

(If you have a specific backwards compatibility problem, you could post that, and someone might know how to workaround the issue.)

Comment: I just downgraded an application to Servlet 2.5 Specification because our WAS8.0 insisted on using this specification level. So.. although I don't know how to control it, it seems to be possible to use Servlet 2.5 with WAS8.0